# Rails render a partial with collection twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this:

```
<%= render :partial => "rewards", :collection => @rewards, :as => :reward %>
```

when I count the items in the collection with `<%= @rewards.count %>`, it shows 1, and I check ed the db that there is only one reward. However, the partial is rendered twice in my master view, with the second one empty (reward == nil). Any clue on this?

Updates:
Found the reason, before this render statement, there is a `user.rewards.build` statement for creating a form:

```
<%= render :partial => "form_reward", :locals => {:user => @user, :reward => @user.rewards.build } %>
<%= render :partial => "rewards", :collection => @rewards, :as => :reward, :locals => {:user => @user } %>
```

somehow the partial rendered this object also! I guess this is because name pollution. Now how to overcome this problem then?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render :partial => 'rewards', :object => @rewards, :as => :reward %>
```

You should be able to access it as `reward` to test try this:

```
<%= reward.inspect %>
```

Ohh and of cause if it should be repeatet you should pass it by as a `:collection` instead of `:object` like its in my example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the query where the @rewards is been populated. It seems like there are two objects in the @reward collection one Reward object and a nil object.

You may use the compact method of the collection to remove the nil object.

Comment: It seems strange... I am afraid the cause could be something else... Also i tried to reproduce the issue in my development instance, but i could not...

Comment: I have put more code to my question, once I remove the form partial, then there will not be an addiction reward object then.

Comment: Why don't you try to use a different variable for reward in the first render statement, something like :locals => {:new_reward => ...}. This should help us to confirm is it because of name pollution.